# Android Studio complains about usage of AndroidX dependencies but they are not used

Tags: android-studio, androidx

Using AS Artic Fox 2020.3.1. patch 3, AGT v4.2.2 and Gradle v6.7.1 with my project, AS produces the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesFastDebug'.
This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
```

I do not have any import statements like `import androidx....` anymore. Both `android.useAndroidX` and `android.enableJetifier` are `false` and I cannot migrate to AndroidX yet because so many migration errors have to be fixed manually.

I've set minSdkVersion to 21, compileSdkVersion to 28 and targetSdkVersion to 23.

`gradlew app:dependencies` only shows one lib which imports androidx:

```
Gradle annotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'main'. (n)
\--- androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:4.2.1 (n)
```

On another machine I've AS 4.2 installed. Compiling with this version result in no error.

How can I use AS Artic Fox with my project and determine the root cause of the task execution error?

Comment: Post your build.gradle(.kts) file please!

Comment: Is it sufficient to link the repository here?
https://github.com/tolot27/xDrip/tree/avoidAndroidX